# How to normalize or standardize the data having multiple columns/variables in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics

I am new to apache spark and scala. I have data set like this which I am taking from csv file and converting it into RDD using scala.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| recent    | Freq      | Monitor  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|        1  |       1234 |   199090|
|        4  |       2553|    198613|
|        6  |       3232 |   199090|
|        1  |       8823 |   498831|
|        7  |       2902 |   890000|
|        8  |       7991 |   081097|
|        9  |       7391 |   432370|
|        12 |       6138 |   864981|
|        7  |       6812 |   749821|
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I want to calculate z-score value or to standardize the data. So I am calculating the z-score for each column and then try to combine them so I get standard scale.

Here is my code for calculating the z-score for first column

```
val scores1 = sorted.map(_.split(",")(0)).cache
val count = scores.count
val mean = scores.sum / count
val devs = scores.map(score => (score - mean) * (score - mean))
val stddev = Math.sqrt(devs.sum / count)
val zscore = sorted.map(x => math.round((x.toDouble - mean)/stddev))
```

How do I calculate for each column ? Or is there any other way to normalize or standardize the data ?

My requirement is to assign the rank(or scale).

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you want to standardize the columns, you can use the [StandardScaler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#standardscaler) class from Spark MLlib. Data should be in the form of `RDD[Vectors[Double]`, where Vectors are a part of `MLlib Linalg` package. You can choose to use mean or standard deviation or both to standardize your data.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val data = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Array(1.0,2.0,3.0),
    Array(4.0,5.0,6.0),
    Array(7.0,8.0,9.0),
    Array(10.0,11.0,12.0)))

// Converting RDD[Array] to RDD[Vectors]
val features = data.map(a => Vectors.dense(a))
// Creating a Scaler model that standardizes with both mean and SD
val scaler = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = true).fit(features)
// Scale features using the scaler model
val scaledFeatures = scaler.transform(features)
```

This `scaledFeatures` RDD contains the Z-score of all columns.

Hope this answer helps. Check the Documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I ran your code with your data its working fine but when tried with integer data I am getting below error

Comment: scala> val features = data.map(a => Vectors.dense(a))
<console>:25: error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
  (values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector <and>
  (firstValue: Double,otherValues: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
 cannot be applied to (Array[_24])
         val features = data.map(a => Vectors.dense(a))'

Comment: Yes MLlib vectors cannot work with Integer types. So you should convert all the values to Double before converting the Arrays into Vectors.

Comment: ok thanks. Just one quick question I want to rank this data so do I need to rank it by sorting the data then normalize or vice versa. Sorry I am just confused in ranking.

Comment: If it helped, accept this answer for this question. :) Sorting it first or last will not make any difference to the result you get.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use below code to perform Standard Scaling on required columns.Vector Assembler is used to select required columns that need to be transformed. StandardScaler constructor also provides you an option to select values of Mean and Standard deviation

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/user/hadoop/data/your_dataset.csv")
df.show(Int.MaxValue)

val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("recent","Freq","Monitor")).setOutputCol("features")

val transformVector = assembler.transform(df)

val scaler = new StandardScaler().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("scaledFeatures").setWithStd(true).setWithMean(false)

val scalerModel = scaler.fit(transformVector)
val scaledData = scalerModel.transform(transformVector)

scaledData.show() 20, False
scaledData.show(Int.MaxValue)
scaledData.show(20, false)
```

Comment: I'm trying MinMaxScaler, but it take days to finish. Is there any faster implementation?